# Salvar múltiplas images em um loop php

Tags: php, laravel

Pessoal tenho o código abaixo no Laravel que salva uma única imagem e funciona corretamente. Mas gostaria de salvar múltiplas imagens que vem de um input que esta como name:"nome[]" multiple. Creio que precisaria de um for mas não consegui fazer funcionar.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $modality = new Modality($input);
    $modality->save();

    $image = $request->image; //Array de imagens

    $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image = new Image();
    $image->name = $imageName;
    $image->imageable_id = $modality->id;
    $image->imageable_type = Modality::class;
    $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public', $imageName);
    $image->save();
    return redirect()->action('ModalityController@index');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lógica inicial é utilizando `foreach` para varrer todos os itens da lista de imagens como demostrado logo abaixo:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $modality = new Modality($input);
    $modality->save();

    //Declarado com o nome da variável $images  
    $images = $request->image; //Array de imagens

    ///////// FOREACH da lista de imagens.
    foreach($images as $im)
    {
        $image = new Image();
        $image->name = $im->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->imageable_id = $modality->id;
        $image->imageable_type = Modality::class;
        $path = $im->storeAs('public', $im->getClientOriginalName());
        $image->save();    
    }
    return redirect()->action('ModalityController@index');

}
```

Comment: No seu código está dando erro no $file.

Comment: Alterei para: $path = $value->storeAs('public', $value->getClientOriginalName()); e funcionou.

Comment: @Marcelo é `$im` na verdade foi um erro de digitação.!

Comment: Certo. Funcionou, obrigado.